# Calculating the area of a roof using vertical and horizontal planes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area

So I'm trying to find the area of a roof of a small cottage.

The base of the shed lies in the x-y plane

The four walls lie in the vertical planes

$x=-4$

$x=4$

$y=-6$

$y=6$

The four sections of the roof lie in the planes given by;

$x + 4z = 12$

$x − 4z = −12$

$y + z = 8$

$y − z = −8$

I'll attach a picture of what I think this is going to look like [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpWfK.png)

I'm stuck at the beginning here which is unfortunate, should I go along rearranging my equations given to try and find ways to solve simple areas of rectangles and triangles? I'  not totally sure.

Thank you in advance for any help. Have a good day.

Comment: The roof consists of two triangles and two trapezoids. The vertices are the intersections of various sets of three planes. Once you have those, you can use standard formulas for the respective areas.

Comment: @amd Would finding intersections be something like equating the sections of the roof to each other and finding the sections by the triangle method? As in I'd think to let xy = 0, then xz and yz to find intercepts. I'd probably have to do this four times maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four corners of the roof are obviously at $x=\pm4$, $y=\pm6$. You can find the tops of the walls by plugging these values into the roof planes and taking the smallest $z$-value, 2. Now, you just need the coordinates of the ends of the roof’s peak, which are the intersections of the roof planes taken three at a time. Taking the first three, we can solve the system of equations by Gaussian elimination: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&4&12\\1&0&-4&-12\\0&1&1&8\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&5\\0&0&1&3\end{bmatrix},$$ i.e., the intersection point is $(0,5,3)$. By symmetry, the other is $(0,-5,3)$.

Finding the roof area is then just a matter of computing the areas of the two triangles and two trapezoids formed by these points. Again, by symmetry, you only need to compute one triangle and one trapezoid and double the total. One of the triangles has vertices $(4,6,2)$, $(-4,6,2)$, $(0,5,3)$. The height of this triangle is the distance between the midpoint of the top of the wall, $(0,6,2)$, and the peak, and the width is $8$, so its area is $\frac12 \cdot 8 \cdot \sqrt2 = 4\sqrt2$. Another way to compute this is via cross products: if the vertices of a triangle in 3-D are $\mathbf p_1$, $\mathbf p_2$ and $\mathbf p_3$, then the area of the triangle is $\frac12\|(\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_3)\times(\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_3)\|$. Using this formula, we have $$((4,6,2)-(0,5,3))\times((-4,6,2)-(0,5,3)) = (0,8,8),$$ so the triangle’s area is $\frac12\sqrt{8^2+8^2} = \frac12\cdot8\sqrt2=4\sqrt2$.

The vertices of one of the trapezoids are $(4,6,2)$, $(4,-6,2)$, $(0,-5,3)$ and $(0,5,3)$. You could work out the distance between the top and bottom of this trapezoid: $\|(4,0,2)-(0,0,3)\|=\sqrt{17}$ and use the formula for a trapezoid’s area: $\frac12(10+12)\sqrt{17}=11\sqrt{17}$, or decompose it into a pair of triangles and use the above cross-product formula:

[image]$$\frac12\|((0,5,3)-(4,6,2))\times((0,-5,3)-(4,6,2))\| = \frac12\|(10,0,40)\| = 5\sqrt{17} \\
\frac12\|((4,6,2)-(0,-5,3))\times((4,-6,2)-(0,-5,3))\| = \frac12\|(-12,0,-48)\| = 6\sqrt{17},$$ and so the area of the trapezoid is $11\sqrt{17}$, making the total area of the roof $8\sqrt2+22\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: This is brilliant I'm going to dive in and try to be able to do this on my own and understand where you are coming from. Thank you for this effort.